# split Table column's into two columns( borders attached to the main row)

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html-table

I am trying to create this layout using Bootstrap Table:

[image: Table layout]

So far I have created two rowrs in which "text1", "text2" and "text3" are created. In "text1" and "text3" `td` I have given `rowSpan` to span it so that I can put the content in between next row on bottom of "text2".

Now the problem i am facing is to **split the Text4 and Text5 in seperate columns**.

I have tried to put nested `tr` and `td` in next row but due to padding around the content, border is coming across and layout is not rendering properly.

Adding the code snippet:

```
<Tables bordered>
<tr>
    <td rowSpan={2}>
        text 1
        </td>
    <td >
        text 2
        </td>
    <td rowSpan={2}>
        text3
        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    text4
                    </Col>
                <Col>
                    text5
                    </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `colspan="2"` to the cell that contains "text 2" and make the cells which contain "text4" and "text5" regular cells (`td`) without any attributes or extra nesting

In plain HTML:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  min-width: 60%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      text 1
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      text 2
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2">
      text3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      text4
    </td>
    <td>
      text5
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```